# How to redirect from OnActionExecution to an Action in a controller (Asp.net core 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net5, onactionexecuting

Hi guys I’m working on an `Asp.net core` project targeted `.Net 5`

I created a class inherited from `IActionFilter` and I used the `OnActionExecution` method I did some logic in it and wanna redirect from it to another `Action` in a `Controller`.

**The problem :**
The problem is how can I redirect to the action that `request` came from and I tried many solution depending on my knowledge but no one succeeds.

**What I tried :**

```
       public class ValidationFilterAttribute : IActionFilter
        {
            public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
            {
                
 //some logic to get the model
                if(!context.ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    Context.Result = new RedirectToAction(“Idon’t know how to get action”, “I don’t know how to get controller”,new{model= /*model I got*/});
                }
            }
            public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
            {          
            }
        }
```

**Question :**
I have two questions,

1. How to know the `Action` and the `Controller` names that request came from ?
2. How can I redirect to the same `Action` but in the same `Controller` and send the same model gotten in ‘OnActionExecution’

**Why I do that :**
My Idea is using my own ‘IActionFilter’ class with any method worked in `HttpPost` To check if the `model` sent is valid or not and if not valid On `OnActionExecution` method will add `errors` to the `model` and resent it again to the action.

Please any help about this issue  ?

Comment: *redirect to the same Action* - are you sure it's the same action or ***another*** action? If it's the same action, it's kind of an unnecessary redirection.

Comment: I’m sure the same action works in HttpPost

Comment: I wanna use redirection to fill modelState with errors catched in OnActionExecuting

Comment: I meant, for example, the current action is `PostSomething` and you want to redirect to that same action? that makes no sense and can be unnecessary. After modifying the data, you can just let that action ***continue*** without having to redirect to it to start over a new request (moreover that way may cause an infinite loop of redirections and result in too-many-redirect error if you don't handle it correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom ActionFilter like this

```
    public class ValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
            public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                 var controllerName =  filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName; // Get controller name

                 var modelState = (filterContext.Controller. as Controller).ViewData.ModelState; // Get the model state of the request
                 var model = (filterContext.Controller as Controller).ViewData.Model; // Get the model of the request

                 //do your stuff here

                  base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
             }
       }
```

And then register your filter so it will be applied to every controller and every action in your project

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddMvcCore(options =>
     {
         options.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidationFilterAttribute));
     });
 }
```

This way before hitting the controller's action method body each request will pass through your `ValidationFilterAttribute` where you can examine his `Model` and change his `ModelState`.

Comment: Firstly thank you fr yor effort and time 
the problem is I din't find `ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName` in `context.ActionDescriptor` 
Note:
Iuse .Net 5 and Asp.net core MVC 5

Comment: How to redirect to the same action and send the mode after added some errors to it ?

Comment: That is my point. You don't have to make a redirect just change the model state however you want and call `base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);` which will just continue the flow and the request will be passed to controller action method. As for `ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName` as far as I see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.actionexecutingcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0 you can access the `ModelState` and `Controller` directly from `filterContext` i.e. `filterContext.ModelState` and `filterContext.Controller`

Comment: Thank you bother but I hav last question how to add catched errors to the model state from `OnActionExecuting` ??

Comment: What do you mean by `catched errors` where these errors are thrown and watched? If you want to catch the exceptions that are generated in the controller you need exception filters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#exception-filters

Comment: When I submit a view form the OnActionExecuting will get the model and if it is not valud I will `foreach` all errors in `modelState` and add it to the modelState, and return the same action with the model errors shown in view usin `Asp-validation-for` And `validation-summary`